# How to get value of uiTextField created programmatically in a uiTableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm a beginner in `iOS` and I try to get the value of my uiTextField that I created programmatically.

So my problem is that I create a form in an UITableViewController with a .json file. I have created my form, but I don't know how I can get the different values.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I created my different elements (I have textFields, textFields with picker and uiswitch). When the user have finished to fill out the form, he click on a "save" button and it is here that I want to get my values.

If someone can help me and put some code for explain .... :) Thanks.

some of my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSString *cellValue = [self getItemName:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

NSString *itemType=[self getItemType:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@",itemType);

if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    UITextField *Reference = [self createTextField];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Reference];
}else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"checkbox"]) {
    UIView *checkbox = [self createCheckbox:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkbox];
}else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"picker"]) {
    UITextField *Reference = [self createPicker:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Reference];
}else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"datePicker"]) {
    UITextField *Reference = [self createDatePicker];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Reference];
}
return cell;
}
```

it is here that i create dynamically the elements. For example an uixtField :

```
-(UITextField*)createTextField{
UITextField *Reference = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200 , 10, 200, 40)];
Reference.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
Reference.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;

Reference.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
Reference.tag=_tag;
_tag++;
return Reference;
}
```

http://hpics.li/04b98ca
here it is an example of that i obtained with my dynamical generation.

Comment: can you explain more with few code if possible? and you can get textfield value by textfield.text method

Comment: It would be better if you would add a screen shot so that we can know what are you doing, we usually get the values by row numbers in UITableView, assigning a tag for same fields like Text field, making separate outlets to get there values are available options

Comment: you should rather use a UIScrollView instead of UITableView to place your form elements.

Comment: How many textfield do you have in your table view?

Comment: Create a custom cell and put all subviews as property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my problem, I have create a `NSMutableDictionary`in which i put my element like that :

key : "name"

value : "`UITextField`"

Like that i can get the textField everywhere in my class.

in .h file

create the dictionary

in .m

just put the element and when you want to go the text value do :

```
UITextField* myTextField= [dictionnary objectForKey:key];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`[textField setTag:(integer value)]`

when you creating fields in `cellForRow...` method.

Then use in `saveMethod` this:

`[[tableView cellForIndexPath:indexPath] viewWithTag:(integer value)]`

for get concrete field of concrete cell.

```
if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
    UITextField *Reference = [self createTextField];
    [Reference setTag:1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:Reference];
}

-(void)saveMethod
{
    NSString *string = [[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] viewwithTag:1] text];
}
```

Comment: i will try your method. Like it is an 'UITableViewController' i replace "tableView" by "UITableView" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create elements in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath for your cells if after you want to get info from them, because it will be very difficult to get it.

The best way is creating your custom UITableViewCell with all elements you want and after, in the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get the info of your elements.

Comment: Yes, its easier. But the problem is that i don't know what element will be in the row, it depends of my .json file.

Comment: add a id to all your elements in your plist and set this id in the property tag of your element

Answer (score 0):

The way I get an indexPath from a view is by checking the superview until I get the parent cell, then using `-indexPathForCell:`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForView:(UIView *)view
{
    while (view != nil && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        view = view.superview;
    }

    return (UITableViewCell *)view;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForView:(UIView *)view
{
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:[self cellForView:view]];
}
```

---

Overall, this solution will run into problems. Cells do not persist in a table view. As soon as the cell is off the screen it is recycled by the table view.

This means you should not attempt to store data in a cell. A cell is used to present data and get user input, but never store data. Data is meant to be stored in the table data source.

In addition, it means you need to be careful when adding subviews to a cell. As the cell get recycled, the views you added in it's previous use will still be in the cell. You will need to have a cleanup section to `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to remove all the views you previously added.

---

My recommendation is to subclass `UITableViewCell`. You can either have 4 subclasses, one for each JSON type you have, or have 1 subclass which can be instantiated with in the 4 different ways. In my example, I have 1 subclass that can be instantiated 4 different ways.

Keep the different types of cells differentiated by using different reuse identifiers.

Use target/actions and delegates to get input from the controls on the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = nil;
    NSString *itemType=[self getItemType:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",itemType);

    if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        cellIdentifier = @"TextCell";
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"checkbox"]) {
        cellIdentifier = @"CheckboxCell";
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"picker"]) {
        cellIdentifier = @"PickerCell";
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"datePicker"]) {
        cellIdentifier = @"DatePickerCell";
    }

    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"TextCell"]) {
            cell = [MyTableViewCell textCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"CheckboxCell"]) {
            cell = [MyTableViewCell checkboxCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"PickerCell"]) {
            cell = [MyTableViewCell pickerCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        } else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"DatePickerCell"]) {
            cell = [MyTableViewCell datePickerCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
    }

    NSString *itemName = [self getItemName:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = itemName;

    if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"text"]) {
        NSString *itemValue = [self getItemValue:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
        cell.textField.text = itemValue;
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"checkbox"]) {
        BOOL itemChecked = [self getItemChecked:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
        cell.checkbox.selected = itemChecked;
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"picker"]) {
        NSString *itemValue = [self getItemValue:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
        cell.pickerLabel = itemValue;
    } else if ([itemType isEqualToString:@"datePicker"]) {
        NSDate *itemDate = [self getItemDate:indexPath.section and:indexPath.row];
        cell.datePickerLabel = itemDate;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you provide this in swift?because i am experiencing it too.